# Java 8 : Iterating a list and adding items to new map

Tags: java-8

How i can write this code in Java 8?

```
for (Iterator<RecordVo> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            RecordVo recordVo = (RecordVo) iterator.next();         
            ExecutionContext singleThreadExecutionContext = new ExecutionContext();
            singleThreadExecutionContext.put("customerId", recordVo.getCustomerId());
            singleThreadExecutionContext.put("ThreadName", "Thread-"+recordVo.getCustomerId());
            multiThreadExecutionContext.put("Partition - "+recordVo.getCustomerId(), singleThreadExecutionContext);
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need to? What's wrong with this code?

Comment: I am learning Java8 and trying to modify my existing code to 8 lambda. Got stuck at this code snippet. I tried using stream, collect, collectors but unable to move forward

Comment: See, learning a tool means also learning where that tool is useful and where it is not. In this case, streams are not a useful tool. You'll get far more mileage by using `for(each : ofList)` here than from streams, and that's Java 6.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.

Comment: I was trying something like this                                      
`list.forEach(recordVo->multiThreadExecutionContext.put("Partition - "+recordVo.getCustomerId(),new ExecutionContext().put("customerId", recordVo.getCustomerId())));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following?

```
list.stream()
  .map(RecordVo::getCustomerId)
  .map(id -> {
    // create singleThreadExecutionContext as before
    return new SimpleImmutableEntry(id, singleThreadExecutionContext);
  })
.forEach(e -> multiThreadExecutionContext.put("Partition - " + e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
```

I didn't compile it, but you can do that.

Comment: It compiled and worked like a charm. Only modification i did is casting e.getValue to ExecutionContext. . `(ExecutionContext)e.getValue()`  I am using the old way in my code but it is really helpful to know how to do it in Java 8.  Thanks Abhijit.